# Odd results with R and quantmod monthlyReturn function

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'm having odd results with quantmod `monthlyReturn` function. Here is an example:

```
require(quantmod)

getSymbols("VOO")

adj <- Ad(VOO["2010-09"])

monthlyReturn(adj)

(as.numeric(tail(adj)[6]) - as.numeric(adj[1])) / as.numeric(adj[1])
```

The last two commands gives the same answer `0.03559799`

However commands `as.numeric(tail(adj)[6])` and `as.numeric(adj[1])` give me values `92.81556` and `89.62508` respectively and command `(92.81556 - 89.62508)/89.62508` gives a value `0.03559807` which is correct but different from above examples.

Can somebody please explain to me what is wrong and why is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing precision when you print the numbers with so few digits.

```
options(digits=20)
as.numeric(tail(adj)[6]) 
# 92.815557999999995786
as.numeric(adj[1]) 
# 89.625084999999998558

(as.numeric(tail(adj)[6]) - as.numeric(adj[1])) / as.numeric(adj[1]) 
#0.035597991343606506798
(92.815557999999995786 - 89.625084999999998558)/89.625084999999998558 
#0.035597991343606506798
```